# Composer cannot find Wordpress core package

Tags: wordpress, composer-php

Trying to update a project to wp5 and it seems composer is unable to find wp

```
 composer require johnpbloch/wordpress-core
```

or

```
 composer require johnpbloch/wordpress
```

returns something like:

> [InvalidArgumentException]   Could not find a matching version of
> package johnpbloch/wordpress-core. Check the package spelling, your
> version constrai   nt and that the package is available in a stability
> which matches your minimum-stability (stable).

This result is replicated using an blank project.

Comment: What does the composer.json look like?

Comment: this package was hosted at wpackagist.org formerly and is now at packagist.org, this was not caused by a typo but a change in address. Thanks for the down votes!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was pretty straight forward, needed to point to packagist.org repos. I had only configured wpackagist.org

If you happen to be migrating from Wordpress 4 to 5 and using composer you will need to change the repo you get this package from.

Doh!